# how to use two connection properties

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-string

how I can set two properties in a connection.

```
Connection conCreate = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rpt"+Globals.comp+"?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8","root","");
```

I want to set rewriteBatchedStatements=true beside useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append your parameter with `&` at the end of your string like:

```
Connection conCreate = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rpt"+Globals.comp+"?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true","root","");
```